# How do I get my regex to exclude the strings indicated in my negative lookahead?

Tags: regex

My regex matches any string containing both numbers and letters, including Roman numerals. Can anyone help me figure out how to exclude the strings indicated in my negative lookahead? I've tried switching to a negative lookbehind and adding a \b boundary, which fixes the issue EXCEPT for the fact that it then will not include the full-width characters because \b does not encompass them. I'm at a loss.

`(?:[０-９0-9]+[ⅠⅡⅢⅣⅥⅦⅧⅨⅪⅫⅤⅩⅬⅭⅮⅯA-zＡ-ｚ]+|[ⅠⅡⅢⅣⅥⅦⅧⅨⅪⅫⅤⅩⅬⅭⅮⅯA-zＡ-ｚ]+[０-９0-9]+)[ⅠⅡⅢⅣⅥⅦⅧⅨⅪⅫⅤⅩⅬⅭⅮⅯA-zＡ-ｚ０-９0-9]*(?!ｍｇ／ｋｇ|mg\/kg|ｎｍ|nm|MHz|ｐｐｍ|ppm|mmol|ｍｍｏｌ|g|ｇ|g|mL|ｍＬ|mol|ｍｏｌ|nM|ｎＭ|μL|v\/v)`

https://regex101.com/r/u82LRb/12

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/jqH77t/1

Comment: I think you can use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/kQm5XR/1). Please provide feedback via a comment to let us know if it works or not, and if not, what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
(?:[０-９0-9]+[ⅠⅡⅢⅣⅥⅦⅧⅨⅪⅫⅤⅩⅬⅭⅮⅯA-Za-zＡ-ｚ]+|[ⅠⅡⅢⅣⅥⅦⅧⅨⅪⅫⅤⅩⅬⅭⅮⅯA-Za-zＡ-ｚ]+[０-９0-9]+)[ⅠⅡⅢⅣⅥⅦⅧⅨⅪⅫⅤⅩⅬⅭⅮⅯA-Za-zＡ-ｚ０-９0-9]*(?!\p{L})(?<!ｍｇ(?=／ｋｇ)|mg(?=\/kg)|ｎｍ|nm|MHz|ｐｐｍ|ppm|mmol|ｍｍｏｌ|mL|ｍＬ|mol|ｍｏｌ|nM|ｎＭ|μL|v(?=\/v)|[gｇ])
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/JePXXY/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [０-９0-9]+           any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more times 
                           (matching the most  amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ⅠⅡⅢⅣⅥⅦⅧⅨⅪⅫⅤⅩⅬⅭⅮⅯ       any Roman number or 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z'
     A-Za-zＡ-ｚ]+                   or 'Ａ' to 'ｚ'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ⅠⅡⅢⅣⅥⅦⅧⅨⅪⅫⅤⅩⅬⅭⅮⅯ       any Roman number or 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z'
     A-Za-zＡ-ｚ]+                   or 'Ａ' to 'ｚ'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [０-９0-9]+              any character of: '0' to '9'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [ⅠⅡⅢⅣⅥⅦⅧⅨⅪⅫⅤ       any Roman number, or 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z'
  ⅩⅬⅭⅮⅯA-Za-z             or 'Ａ' to 'ｚ'
  Ａ-ｚ０-９0-9]*          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \p{L}                    any Unicode letter character 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ｍｇ                    'ｍｇ'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ／ｋｇ                      '／ｋｇ'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mg                       'mg'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \/kg                       '/kg'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ｎｍ                     'ｎｍ'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    nm                       'nm'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    MHz                      'MHz'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ｐｐｍ                  'ｐｐｍ'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ppm                      'ppm'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mmol                     'mmol'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ｍｍｏｌ                'ｍｍｏｌ'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mL                       'mL'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ｍＬ                  'ｍＬ'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mol                      'mol'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ｍｏｌ                  'ｍｏｌ'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    nM                       'nM'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ｎＭ                      'ｎＭ'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    μL                  'μL'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    v                        'v'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \/v                        '/v'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [gｇ]                   any character of: 'g' or 'ｇ'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your help! After looking through all your suggestions and trying out different things, this final regex ended up doing what I needed it to with a few more specifics:

```
(?:[０-９0-9⁰-⁹₀-₉]+[μⅠⅡⅢⅣⅥⅦⅧⅨⅪⅫⅤⅩⅬⅭⅮⅯa-zａ-ｚA-ZＡ-Ｚ]+|[μⅠⅡⅢⅣⅥⅦⅧⅨⅪⅫⅤⅩⅬⅭⅮⅯa-zａ-ｚA-ZＡ-Ｚ]+[０-９0-9⁰-⁹₀-₉]+)[μⅠⅡⅢⅣⅥⅦⅧⅨⅪⅫⅤⅩⅬⅭⅮⅯa-zａ-ｚA-ZＡ-Ｚ０-９0-9⁰-⁹₀-₉]*|
[０-９0-9⁰-⁹₀-₉]+(?! grams)(?: mm| cm| nm| M| ppm| g | mg| kg| μL| μm| μmol| μg| μM| ng| mol| mmol| mM| nM| mL| v\/v| U| rpm|重量ｐｐｍ|重量％ｐｐｍ|モル| W| kcal| GHz| pF| fF| dB| V| m2)
```